# how to globalize a variable that is in a function

Tags: javascript

I would like to ask you to help me solve the following question which is giving me trouble: How do I isolate the `latitude` and `longitude` variables to display them outside the function

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getLatLon);
function getLatLon(position) {
    var latitude = "";
    var longitude = "";
    latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    longitude = position.coords.longitude;
}
document.write("Latitude is "+latitude);
document.write("Longitude is "+longitude);
```

Comment: But you function is never called?

Answer (score -1):

```
var latitude;
var longitude;

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getLatLon);
function getLatLon(position) {
  latitude = "";
  longitude = "";
 latitude = position.coords.latitude;
 longitude = position.coords.longitude;
}
document.write("Latitude is "+latitude);
document.write("Longitude is "+longitude)
```

declare them outside of the function or at the top of your script file(global variables)